# SQL multi-column ordering with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried this:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,company_name FROM users ORDER BY last_name, company_name ASC
```

I have a `users` table like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| first_name       | last_name          | company_name       |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Alfa             | Alfa               | Bravo              |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Echo             | Echo               | Alfa               |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Delta            | Delta              |                    |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  |                    | Charlie            |
+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The order of the rows at the moment is:

```
 , ,Charlie
Alfa, Alfa, Bravo
Delta, Delta,
Echo, Echo, Alfa
```

What I would like to achieve, is to order rows primarily by last_name but if it's not available (empty), order by company_name but in a way that it still compares this company_name-column with the last_name-columns... Sorry for possible inaccurate explanation. Here is the order I'd like to achieve:

```
Alfa, Alfa, Bravo
 , ,Charlie
Delta, Delta,
Echo, Echo, Alfa
```

**EDIT:** Is this possible via a single MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISNULL()` function. If the `last_name` value is `NULL`, then it'll use the `company_name` value for ordering instead.

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(last_name, company_name)
```

If your last_name is not NULL, and just a blank string, you can use the NULLIF() function to get around this:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(NULLIF(last_name,''), company_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Curt! Had to use IFNULL instead of ISNULL for MySQL, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,company_name 
FROM users ORDER BY coalesce(last_name, company_name) ASC
```

`COALESCE` is ANSI SQL Compatible, BTW.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The order is still the same as my original one.

Comment: Are the empty fields set to null or just blank? (You know there's a difference right?)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. No, the fields are not null, just blank. I tested it with NULL values and that's it. Works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY COALESCE(last_name, company_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle, empty VARCHAR columns are treated as NULL. Then use `COALESCE` or `NVL` as suggested above.

Else, if there is an empty string in your column (not NULL) you can use `ORDER BY CASE last_name WHEN '' THEN ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column to the query:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,company_name,
case when last_name is null 
then company_name
else last_name
end as ord 
FROM users ORDER BY ord  ASC
```